# how to open lwc without vscode salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code

How can I check the code (for lwc as js and html code) in salesforce without vscode.
I can not see the code in developer console

Comment: You could use my my extension  to edit LWC components. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-advanced-code/lnkgcmpjkkkeffambkllliefdpjdklmi?hl=en  You can read about it here:https://jungleeforce.com/2020/10/13/salesforce-lwc-editor-in-browser/

Answer (score 5):

Lightning Web Components are not accessible through the developer console.

If you need to extract the code from a LWC ing your org, then you can do so with the following steps:

Step 1. Go to workbench and login.

https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Step 2.  Click on retrieve button.

Step 3. click on "Choose File" button and upload package.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <version>45.0</version>
</Package>
```

Step 4. click on next and retrieve metadata, it will give you all the LWC components exist in your org.

Step 5. click Download ZIP File.

Comment: Thanks Jordan! For anyone wondering, the process Jordan describes here is super quick and easy. I had never used workbench before and was able to get my LWC files in under two minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot view that in the developer console.

If you want to retrieve the code there are few options.

- Using vs code (this is the recommended way for development).
- Using salesforce CLI - (Internally used by VS code).
- Using Ant migration tools
- Using Workbench and package.xml file.

For LWC development, you need to set up your developer tools, [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/set-up-your-lightning-web-components-developer-tools) is the trailhead.

Answer (score 2):

Found a very handy chrome extension for viewing and editing LWC's: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-lwc-editor/ehkpneicmpbdejpoancidgkejlkahjgo/related?hl=en-US

Answer (score 1):

As per this [Salesforce developer blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/12/developer-tools-for-lightning-web-components.html) :

> **You can only develop Lightning web components using the Salesforce CLI and an IDE (or text editor)**. The developer console is a convenient tool that’s used daily by many Salesforce developers. You can still use it to access Apex classes, Visualforce pages and Aura bundles; however, it’s not a full-blown IDE. Also, in its current form, the **developer console can’t provide integrated support for much of the tooling that ships with the Lightning Web Components Salesforce Extension, like ESLint**.
>
> You’ll get the best developer experience using more robust tools like VS Code and the Salesforce Extensions, or Illuminated Cloud. Your users will also benefit because these tools can help you identify and avoid common issues in your code as you write, and before you even try to deploy to development environments.

So developer console is currently not supported for LWC, you can also check this open idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TzBNQA0)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is a way but it is weird and based on the aforementioned background processes:

Send a **changeset** with the component and examine the *uploaded* changeset source. It is bundled so all css, javascript and markup display in one page. If the source is already in prod, check the the deployed source and view it from there.

This is obviously not ideal and would require a lot of effort to do continuously but it is an alternative in some cases where one needs to view the markup quickly without having to install the utilities and get the development environment up.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tried this but looks interesting: [LWC Developer Console](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000MBZArEAP&placement=a0d3u000008QCZfAAO&tab=e)